# Converting single entries into an array with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have 3 tables of data. Table `A`,  `AC` and `C`. Table `AC` simply connects `A` and `C` together with a ForeignKey. Currently all my rows in `AC` are single entries that create these connections. So my question in this matter arises whether it makes sense to convert all the single entries in `AC` into one row for each `A` entry.

The connections that occur between `A` and `C` is one-to-many, so the array length is basically `1..x`. The mean entry amount in table `AC` for each `A` entry is around 6, so it would reduce the entries in `AC` significantly if it was changed to arrays.

OR should i instead remove `AC` and simply add the `FK` field to the `A` table instead?

Where at the pitfalls when using arrays in this use-case? Will i have to use JSON style entries in an array: `['blah','blah2','blah3']`?

The example below explains the structure of the database, while values are bogus:

```
Table A
|   id  |   name    |
---------------------
|   1   |   John    |
|   2   |   Jim     |
|   3   |   Joe     |


Table AC
|   id  |   id_a    |   id_c    |
---------------------------------
|   1   |   1       |   1       |
|   2   |   1       |   4       |
|   3   |   2       |   2       |
|   4   |   3       |   3       |
|   5   |   3       |   1       |


Table C
|   id  |   name    |
---------------------
|   1   |   Pie     |
|   2   |   Cake    |
|   3   |   Burger  |
|   4   |   Ice     |
```

Comment: Putting things like than in an array almost never makes sense. First - and most importantly - you lose the ability to define foreign keys. When deleting things from `C` things get really messy as well. When you really, really *need* to de-normalize, using an array is much better than using a comma separated list (but still: it's denormalizing with all its disadvantages)

Comment: Lets pretend i have a great controller that handles all the necessary actions when a entry is deleted from `C`. In that case would it still not be significantly more efficient? Although i do understand your concern with the comma seperated list, i would stick to a pure array.

Comment: Your "great controller" won't be able to guarantee the consistency in the database. You can **not** reliably enforce referential integrity in the application layer (plus: experience shows that hardly any important database will be accessed by only one single application and very often the database lives *much* longer than the application(s) ).

Comment: Unfortunately thats a true fact. What if i built the automated behavior into the database itself, instead of a application controller?

Comment: Which would simply mean that you re-build constraint checking with means of the database on top of the built-in constraint checking already available in the database - why not use the tried and robust solution available. Plus: unless you do have a performance problem *now* just stick to the current design. This kind of mapping is pretty standard and works well even for large databases.

Comment: Foreign key arrays were tested out for PostgreSQL in the 9.4 development series, but the patch performed quite poorly and was not accepted. It turns out that reliably checking foreign keys in arrays is hard. I suggest reading the discussion history on pgsql-hackers. Really, don't reinvent this wheel. Unless you have a strong need, keep things normalised.